# Eclipse Mars & Subversion & JavaHL: How to let eclipse store the repository password?

Tags: eclipse, macos, svn, subclipse, javahl

I know this has been asked many times before but no method is working for me!

I have Eclipse Mars Mars 2 (4.5.2), Subclipse 1.10.9, Subversion Client Adapter 1.10.3, JavaHL Native Library Adapter 1.18.13 and on my mac installed with brew: subversion 1.8.13.

I can access the remote repository but I have to enter the password the password multiple times. This is driving me nuts.

I have actived JavaHL in the team->svn settings as the SVN client: JavaHL (JNI) 1.8.13 (r1667537).

This is what I have tried so far:

- Delete the default secure storage (General->Security->Secure Storage)
- Activated both OSX Keystore Integration and UI Prompt as password providers (General->Security->Secure Storage)
- Activated only OSX Keystore Integration
- Activated only UI Prompt
- Changed the master password (General->Security->Secure Storage)
- Deleted the eclipse_keyring
- Deleted the .eclipse folder
- Deleted the .subversion folder
- Deleted the entry in the OS X keychain
- Started eclipse with -clean and -initialize

Now I just tried to install SVNKit but it doesn't show up in the team->svn settings. I would prefer to stay with JavaHL anyway because merging with svnkit seems to have issues.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are stored by the Subversion API provider (JavaHL or SVNKit). JavaHL is native code and not aware of Eclipse.  It has its own storage mechanisms.  On OSX this is the OSX Keychain.  You will typically get prompted by OSX to allow access to the keychain the first time a native binary tries to do this.  Perhaps you said No?  I would guess this is stored in the Keychain app somewhere.

Other than that, Subversion's configuration file determines if it will store passwords. This is the [auth] section of ~/.subversion/config. Usually all settings are commented out, which means you will get the default behavior which is to store passwords and in the case of OSX, using they keychain.  But if settings are uncommented, you can turn off password storage or override where it is stored.  So it is worth checking this file.  Since you said you deleted .subversion it should have been auto-recreated with all the defaults.

Basically it should be working without doing anything special.  Maybe this gives you the right things to look at though.  There are no settings in Eclipse that control this.

Comment: This information was useful but I can't up vote yet. What actually helped me was to re-install eclipse. Perhaps the update mechanism screwed something up?

Comment: That could be a sign you answered No when OSX asked for Permission to use your keychain.  When you reinstall Eclipse, this would be reset and you would have been asked again.